# SQL to extract matlab date from postgres db

Tags: sql, postgresql, matlab

I'd like to construct a query to "convert" a postgresql datetime to a matlab datenum.  Experience with other DBs has shown me that converting the date on the DB side is *much* faster than doing it in matlab.

Matlab stores dates as number of days (including fractions) since an arbitrary epoch of a gregorian, non-existent date of 00-00-0000.

On Oracle, it's simple, because Oracle stores dates internally like matlab does, but with a different epoch.

```
select (date_column_name - to_date('01-Jan-0001') + 365) ...
```

A straightforward conversion of this to PG syntax doesn't work:

```
select (date_column_name - date '01-Jan-0001' + interval 365) ...
```

I've started with a particular day in matlab, for testing:

```
>> num2str(datenum('2010-10-02 12:00'))

ans =

734413.5
```

I've been in and out of the pg docs all day, `extract`ing `epoch`s and `second`s, etc.  And I've gotten close.  Basically this gets the seconds in an interval, which I just divide by the seconds in a day:

```
Select cast(extract(epoch from (timestamp '2010-10-02 12:00' 
                               - timestamp '0000-01-01 23:10'
                               + interval '2 day'
                               )
                   ) as real
           )/(3600.0*24.0)  AS MDate
```

answer:
    734413.51111111111

But that exhibits some bizarre behavior.  Adjusting the minutes from the epoch timestamp doesn't change the answer, except at one particular minute - i.e 23:09 is one answer, 23:10 is another, and it stays the same from 23:10 to 23:59.  (other hours have similar behavior, though the particular "minute" is different.)

Any ideas?  Maybe on another way to do this?

edit:
using 8.4.2

Comment: Which postgresql version are you using? I get an error - 'date/time field value out of range: "0000-01-01 23:10"' trying your query in 8.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the cast was the problem.

```
Select extract(epoch from (timestamp '2010-10-02 12:00:01' 
       - timestamp '0000-01-01 00:00' 
       + interval '1 day'))/(3600.0*24.0)
```

works like a champ.

Comment: I get ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "0000-01-01 00:00".   Actually I have read that there is no year 0000, only 1 BCE then 1 CE.  No Year 0.  Apparently the version of postgres I am using respects this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, extract(epoch from t::timestamp) will give seconds since the UNIX epoch (01 Jan 1970), and produces 1286017200 for '2010-10-02 12:00:00'.

Matlab gives 734413.5 for the same timepoint, but that's in days- so 63453326400 seconds, an offset of 62167309200.

So to convert postgres epoch time to matlab datenum, we should be able to just add that offset and convert back to days.

```
steve=# select (extract(epoch from '2010-10-02 12:00:00'::timestamp) + 62167309200) / (24*3600);
 ?column? 
----------
 734413.5
(1 row)
```